# Unable to locate child elements using uiautomator (java)

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

```
@AndroidFindBy (uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().className(\"android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView\").childSelector(new UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.RelativeLayout\"))")
public List<MobileElement> listOfElements;

System.out.print(listOfElements.size());
```

This returns 1.

So there is an element "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" which contains 9 elements "android.widget.RelativeLayout". Those I want to get a list of, but I get only 1 element with the aforementioned locator. What am I doing wrong here?

If I add .index() at the end of locator, then it will give me an element according to specified index number, but I need a list of all child elements.

And does appium support all UiSelector commands? Because some of them do not seem to be working (like classNameMatches where you can type a regex, or fromParent, scrollable, ...)

Answer (score 0):

you can use parent , child class strategy as below,

```
WebElement l1 = driver.findElementByClassName("android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView\");               
                //All elements in big container L1
                List<WebElement> l2 = l1.findElements(By.className("android.widget.RelativeLayout\));               
                System.out.println("size of L2= " + l2.size());
                for(int i = 0 ; i<l2.size();i++){
                    System.out.println("\n Index is : " + i + "Content-desc is : " + l2.get(i).getAttribute("name"));

            }
```

Modify the loop as per your needs

Comment: Thanks, this I'm aware of, but I'm using PageFactory. And I want to learn to use uiAutomator selectors, but some things are not working for me and that's what I want to figure out.